# How to re-install Google play services

Tags: google-apps

How do you reinstall Google Play store and Google Play services after uninstalling them.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! For a starter, you could check our [google-apps tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info).

Comment: Have you removed the apps or just the updates?

Answer (score 0):

As Firelord asked, did you uninstall the apps or only the updates?

If only the updates, if you open the play store on your phone, and it should seek for updates to both your play store and play services. If it doesn't happen automatically, try clearing the data of the play store app, and then manually trying to find the update by going to the settings activity of the play store and tapping on the version number.

If you've uninstalled the apps, then I presume you already have root access, because uninstalling them without root access is very difficult.
In this case, flash a recovery to your phone if you haven't already, and flash the Google apps zip (GApps) matching your android version, and clear the cache and dalvik cache if necessary through the recovery after the install.